# Grails - render Map from controller via Ajax using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, grails, controller, render

I know this is a recurrent/classical topic but I did not found anything that helped me so far. 
I am trying to render a Map from my controller. This results from an Ajax request and is supposed to be "eaten" by a Javascript function 'onSuccess'.

Here is my **Javascript** and **.gsp view**:

```
<g:javascript>
function updateVideoLoad(e) {
var map = eval("("+e.responseText+")") // evaluate the JSON
$('#resultsChecker').html(map.urlAccepted + ' - ' + map.provider + ' - ' + map.videoId + ' - ' + map.videoTag)
}
</g:javascript>
<g:formRemote name="myForm" update="" url="[controller: 'project', action:'addVideo']" onSuccess="updateVideoLoad(e)">        
    ...      
</g:formRemote>
```

Here is my **controller**:

```
    import grails.converters.JSON

class ProjectController {

    def addVideo() {
       ...
    def videoMap = [urlAccepted: videoList[0], provider: videoList[1], videoId: videoList[2], videoTag: videoList[3]]
    render videoMap as JSON
    }
```

It looks to me exactly as the example provided in the [Grails documentation](http://file:///var/lib/grails-doc-2.0.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajaxOnTheServer).
However it does not work. On the browser console, I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

from my `g:remoteForm`.

Any suggestion is most welcome.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: is this a typo in code or question? <g:formRemote>!=</g:remoteForm>

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to correct it. This was not in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
<g:formRemote name="myForm" update="" url="[controller: 'project', action:'addVideo']" onComplete="updateVideoLoad(XMLHttpRequest)">
```

Is there a place where to get documentation on those javascript events (`onComplete`, `onSuccess`, ...) ?

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Tags/formRemote.html contains events documentation

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but it looks like a mistake in the documentation.  I would expect that this part:

```
 onSuccess="updateVideoLoad(e)"
                           ^^^
```

Should really be:

```
 onSuccess="updateVideoLoad(data,textStatus)"
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looking at the generated code (under Grails 2.0), these are the variables used in the returned:

```
<form onsubmit="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:jQuery(this).serialize(), url:'/project/addVideo',success:function(data,textStatus){updateVideoLoad(e);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false"
    method="post" action="/project/addVideo" id="myForm">
```

Look at the `success` property in the generated code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
I modified the functions as such: 
`onSuccess="updateVideoLoad(data,textStatus)"` and `function updateVideoLoad(data, textStatus) { ... }`. 

Now I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlAccepted' of undefined ("data")`. 

So I moved forward as it seems I am actually calling the javascript function now but am still unable to parse the JSON Map.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a documentation bug.  If using JQuery (the default as of Grails 2.0)  The variable should be 'data' not 'e' and it will contain your JSON object that you returned from your controller, and there is no need to eval or parse it like in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I'm using Dojo.

If you use dojo, you shoud use the variable name 'response':

```
onComplete="updateVideoLoad(response)"
```

It works fine for Dojo.